# Непонятное поведение operator string ()

Tags: c++, классы

Есть некий класс, в очень упрощенном виде выглядит так:

```
class variant
{
public:
    variant (){};

    template <class T>
    operator T ()
    {
        return T(11);
    }

    operator string ()
    {
        string str = "sss";
        return str;
    }
};
```

и есть программа:

```
int main()
{
    variant v1;
    int x1 = v1; // тут все хорошо (вызывается operator int ())
    x1 = v1; // тут тоже все хорошо (вызывается  так же operator int ())

    variant v2;
    string s1 = v2; // тут все хорошо (вызывается operator string ())
    s1 = v2; // тут получаю ошибку компиляции

    return 0;
}
```

немогу понять в чем дело, если задаю переменной типа `string` значение при инициализации то все нормально, но если пытаюсь присвоить переменной типа `string` значение получаю ошибку(с встроенными типами данных все хорошо):

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'variant')
```

что я делаю не так? как правильно перегрузить чтото вроде `string operator= (variant)`?

компилятор: gcc version 5.1.0 (MinGW-W64 project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё просто, в строке `string s1 = v2;` вызывается конструктор копирования `std::string`, у которого есть только один вариант аргумента: `const std::string&`. Поэтому происходит преобразование и всё работает.

С другой стороны, строка `s1 = v2;` вызывает `std::string::operator=` и тут уже вариантов аргументов куда больше, поэтому компилятор не может определить, в какой тип нужно конвертировать `v2`. Вылечить это можно только явным преобразованием.

---

На деле получается, что и с явным преобразованием получается та же ошибка. Дальше будут мои спекуляции почему так происходит, чтобы дать ответ точно — нужно штудировать стандарт.

Итак, строчка `s1 = static_cast<std::string>(v2);` генерирует ту же самую ошибку, тогда как, как заметил Harry, такая строчка: `s1 = static_cast<const std::string&>(v2);` работает как надо. Моё объяснение таково: в первом случае, конвертировать что-то в `std::string` можно из любого типа, одноаргументный конструктор которого имеет `std::string`, поэтому, эта строчка генерирует сразу пачку операторов преобразования и мы опять имеем неоднозначность.

С другой стороны, когда мы пытаемся преобразовать к ссылке на `std::string`, получается, что прямое преобразование побеждает — в непрямом нужно сначала создать `std::string` и только потом можно будет преобразовать к ссылке, т.е. 2 преобразования, а в первом случае нужно только одно.

Что нам всё это даёт? Даёт нам это понимание, что если написать код, который запретит шаблонному оператору преобразования участвовать в операциях, когда происходит конвертация в `std::string`, тогда наш код с преобразованием должен заработать:

```
template<typename T>
using EnableIfNotStr_t = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value>;
class variant
{
public:
    variant() {};

    template <class T, typename = EnableIfNotStr_t<T>>
    operator T ()
    {
        return T(11);
    }

    operator std::string () const
    {
        std::string str = "sss";
        return str;
    }
};
//...
s1 = static_cast<std::string>(v2);
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, а почему вызывается именно конструктор копирования, а не, скажем, преобразующий конструктор от `const char*`

Comment: @ixSci Не в возражение, а для понимания :) - почему не проходит исправление `s1 = static_cast<string>(v2);`, а только `s1 = static_cast<const string&>(v2);`?

Comment: @alexolut, потому что это синтаксис инициализации копированием(copy initialization)

Comment: @ixSci, а это тогда что `string s2 = "char*";`?

Comment: @Harry, хороший вопрос, но я не могу дать на него ответ прямо сейчас, нужно штудировать стандарт

Comment: @alexolut, а это неявное создание `std::string` и вызов конструктора копирования после этого

Comment: @ixSci согласен. Но синтаксис такой же. Вероятно, приоритет копирующего конструктора больше, чем приоритет преобразующего. Вот он и выбирается.

Comment: @ixSci попробовал записать выражение так `s1=(string)v2;` получил примерно такую же ошибку `error: call of overloaded 'basic_string(variant&)' is ambiguous`

Comment: теперь проблема возникла из-за использования шаблона.

Comment: разобрался, явное преобразование нужно делать либо так `s1 = (string&&)v2;` либо так `s1 = (const string&)v2;`, но это не очень красиво, думаю проще создать метод  класса variant::is_string() например.

Comment: @xttz, обновил ответ

Comment: @ixSci единственное ваш ответ работает судя по всему в C++14. у меня в C++11 работает не до конца, получаю ошибку с неоднозначностью, но вариантов не пять, а три.

Comment: @xttz, нет, дело не в C++14, у меня это работает в студии, но я сейчас проверил на clang/gcc — там не работает. Значит где-то баг, но чтобы понять где — нужно понять корректное поведение, если будет время попробую разобраться.